# Search From Multiple Models (Elastic Search)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, ruby-on-rails-6

hope you are fine!
Actually, I have elastic search in my App but I can just search from a single Model at a time. e.g

```
Post.search 'Food'
```

but I want this word Food search from all the models like Restaurants, Blogs, etc in a single Request
how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Multi-search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) for searching across multiple index in a single request.